# How to show Haxe compiled to Javascript Runtime Exceptions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, haxe

I'm working on a Haxe project, where runtime exceptions don't appear from messaging, so if I have a RTE in the messagehandler, I never know if the code didn't executed correctly. How Can I make them appear? 
I'm using chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haxe errors are not special in any way. If you throw (or your code does) you will see the same kind of error messages you are used to get with plain JS. So I guess you should investigate your code for `try/catch` that hide errors and such.

Comment: yeah, probably one of the used libs cause it :(

Comment: I hope it was not one of mine :)